# Number of bits to encode number of accepting paths of an $NP$ machine?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

Can polynomial number of bits always encode the number of accepting paths of an $NP$ machine?

Can polynomial number of bits always encode the number of accepting paths of any machine in the polynomial hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transcript of a computation of a machine in the polynomial hierarchy has polynomial length (since the running time of the machine is polynomial). Hence the total number of computations is $2^{p(n)}$ for some polynomial $p(n)$, and so the number of bits needed to encode the number of accepting computations is $\log [2^{p(n)}] = p(n)$, that is, polynomial.